# Unresolved external symbols in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, unresolved-external, clsid

This is my situation (I am very new to C++ MFC coding and I am trying to debug an existing application project)

I use this line in my code (in a visual studio 2012 MFC project)

> CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PortableDeviceValues, NULL,
>   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&x));

While I run the project, i get a linker error like this

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_PortableDeviceValues

This happens for all the CLSID values that I am referring to in the code. Like this

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _CLSID_PortableDeviceKeyCollection
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IPortableDeviceEventCallback
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_PortableDeviceManager
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_PortableDeviceServiceFTM

I checked for the declaration of "CLSID_PortableDeviceValues" and it was found in "PortableDeviceTypes.h" and I have imported that library as well.

I do not get any compiler error, but run into the linker errors mentioned above..

Can someone please help me out here. I could not resolve this ..

Comment: Which library have you imported as well? *PortableDeviceGUIDs.lib*?

Comment: I just imported PortableDeviceTypes.h in the code..

Comment: Oops, i imported the library you mentioned, and it worked !! thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add **PortableDeviceGUIDs.lib** to your project.
(Look up the section "Requirements" in the [MSDN documentation for IPortableDeviceValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319461.aspx))

When the linker builds your project, it is looking for the implementation data that is behind the identifier `CLSID_PortableDeviceValues`. This data is in the library PortableDeviceGUIDs.lib, and the linker has to be told to use this library.

The header file you included in your source code only declares the symbol "CLSID_PortableDeviceValues", without importing its implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to make WpdApiSample work with VS2010 and it showed these kind of errors when I compile it. The project was updated and it hasn't the correct configuration. I'm very new with C++ by the way.